# List of all entities generated from data model

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, entity-framework

How can I get a list of all Entities Type generated from a Entity data model (*.edmx)?

I already have the names of the tables from the database and an instance of the model (.edmx).

I want to have an instance of Type of  all the data entities.

let's suppose my database have two tables:
Employee
EmployeeType

then the model will generate 2 classes and map the data. What I'm searching is a way to obtain a List(of Type).
In this case, the result list would countain an instance of Employee.GetType() and EmployeeType.getType()

Thanks!

(VS2010, VB.NET, EF4)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the ways to do it is:

```
((EdmItemCollection)ctx
    .MetadataWorkspace
    .GetItemCollection(DataSpace.CSpace))
    .GetItems<EntityType>()
```

I have not tried it before but you may be even able to get the items directly from the workspace:

```
ctx.MetadataWorkspace.GetItems<EntityType>(DataSpace.CSpace)
```

If you are using DbContext you can get ObjectContext as follows:

```
((IObjectContextAdapter)ctx).ObjectContext
```

Answer (score 0):

```
using (AdventureWorksEntities context = new AdventureWorksEntities())
{
    IQueryable<Product> productsQuery = from product in context.Products
                                        select product;

    Console.WriteLine("Product Names:");
    foreach (var prod in productsQuery)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(prod.Name);
    }
}
```

[Object Queries - MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb896241%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

Comment: I want the Type, not the data. Thanks